# How to Count Possible Orderings of Digits with Required Substrings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question is as follows:

> How many orderings of the digits from 1 to 8 contain the sub-strings 12,
>   23 or 34? For example, 57238614 is one such ordering since 23 appears, and
>   12345678 works, too, since this is not the exclusive or. However, 73184625 is
>   NOT such an ordering. No repeated digits allowed.

I'm taking [12] [23] and [34] as numbers that must be chosen individually.
Therefore,

[12] _ _ _ _ _ _
gives us 6 options for the 1st digit, 5 options for the 2nd, 4 for the 3rd, etc... Therefore, we end up with 6! * 7 positions that the [12] can be in. Therefore, there are 7! permutations for this group.

[23] _ _ _ _ _ _ Similar logic as above, we end up with 7! permutations.

[34] _ _ _ _ _ _ Similar logic as the first, 7! permutations.

However, we end up over-counting and that is where I start to get confused a bit.

[123] _ _ _ _ _ gives us 6! permutations.

[12][34] _ _ _ _ is another such situation, but I'm not sure how to count this one.

Is there any other combination that I'm missing? Is my logic even sound?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_exclusion) problem.

Let $S$ denote all the orderings. $|S|=8!$.

Let $A$ denote those orderings where $1$ immediately precedes $2$.  You've counted, correctly, that $|A|=7!$.

Let $B$ denote those orderings where $2$ immediately precedes $3$.  Let $C$ denote those where $3$ immediately precedes $4$.  You've correctly concluded that $|B|=|C|=7!$.

The desired quantity is $|S|-|A|-|B|-|C|+|A\cap B| + |A\cap C|+|B \cap C|-|A\cap B\cap C|$, and you're on the way to getting it.  The last situation, that you called [12][34]_ _ _ _, is $A\cap C$, and there are $6!$ such orderings, since we have two "numbers" [12] and [34], and four other numbers.

The remaining details I leave for you to determine.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you! Great to know the type of problem and steering me in the right direction. Have a great day!

Comment: @thiefjack, my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

Pack $\underline {23}$  as an unit. Then permute the other $6$ numbers.